# Message SONARqube - Restrict what this loop acts on by testing each property

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

The code snippet is receiving criticism below SONARqube. Would you like to understand what needs to be done to correct the problem?

```
for (var ev in options.events) {
    (function(object, name) {
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(object, name, function(){
        options.events[name].apply(this, [this]);
      });
    })(control, ev);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: The first thing to do is click on "See Rule" next to the message.  That generally gives you a lot of information about what Sonar is trying to warn you about.

Comment: I saw the suggestions in Compliant Soluction, but they didn't work. So I ask for help from you more experienced.

Comment: See https://sonarsource.github.io/rspec/#/rspec/S1535/javascript

Answer (score 0):

The `for...in` statement allows you to loop through the names of all of the properties of an object. The list of properties includes all those properties that were inherited through the prototype chain. This has the side effect of serving up functions when the interest is in data properties. Programs that don’t take this into account can fail.

Therefore, the body of every `for...in` statement should be wrapped in an if statement that filters which properties are acted upon. It can select for a particular type or range of values, or it can exclude functions, or it can exclude properties from the prototype.

Noncompliant Code Example

```
for (name in object) {
    doSomething(name);  // Noncompliant
}
```

Compliant Solution

```
for (name in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    doSomething(name);
  }
}
```

Exceptions
Loops used to clone objects are ignored.

```
for (prop in obj) {
  a[prop] = obj[prop];  // Compliant by exception
}
```